# Unable to combine conditions with SDO_CONTAINS/SDO_RELATE

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I have two tables, one containing the country borders, and one containing a feature (cables for instance), and I want to know in which country they are located.

So I use the following query:

```
select cc.country_code, ca.*
from CABLES ca, COUNTRIES cc
where sdo_contains(cc.geometry, ca.geometry) = 'TRUE'
```

This works: I get a clear list with for each cable a country-code.

Now I want to select all cables lying in the Netherlands, so I write something like:

```
select cc.country_code, ca.*
from CABLES ca, COUNTRIES cc
where sdo_contains(cc.geometry, ca.geometry) = 'TRUE'
  and cc.country_code = 'NL'
```

and suddenly I get `no rows selected` ?

I tried various alternatives: using subqueries, with-clause, sdo_relate and they all have the same effect: no rows selected. I tried using a view, but I guess that has the same effect as writing a subquery internally.

When using `SDO_ANYINTERACT` I am able to add the condition `country_code = 'NL'` and get some results, but it does not give me the same results (obviously?).

Weird thing defining the view as follows:

```
create or replace view cables_with_country as 
  select cc.country_code, ca.*
  from cables ca, countries cc
  where (sdo_contains(cc.geometry, ca.geometry) = 'TRUE')
```

and then doing a `select count(*) from cables_with_country` returns 0 ???

The only solution that has worked so far is using a materialized view:

```
create materialized view cables_with_country_mv as 
  select cc.country_code, ca.*
  from cables ca, countries cc
  where (sdo_contains(cc.geometry, ca.geometry) = 'TRUE')
```

Can anybody explain why I see this strange behaviour and how I could best tackle this? Using the materialized view feels hackish at best.

Comment: does the result of your first query contain any rows with 'NL' as country code?

Comment: My first query returns 723 rows with 'NL' as country code. Maybe it was not clear enough, but it works correctly (and only works) if I convert the query to a materialized view first. I would assume that subqueries or extra conditions  would just work similarly and I am a bit baffled it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `/*+ ordered */` hint

in your case, the SQL should be like this:

```
select /*+ ORDERED */ 
cc.country_code, ca.all
from  COUNTRIES cc,CABLES ca -- in this order
where sdo_contains(ca.geometry,cc.geometry) = 'TRUE'
  and cc.country_code = 'NL';
```

Note that I have changed the `sdo_contains`, because country has cables inside... in your query was otherwise